# Multiple $http calls doesn't return in the right order

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I made a `for` loop and inside I make a `$http` call to my API.
The `for` loop makes the calls in a specific order, but how I get the reponse is totally messed up..

This is my code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < amountOfEntries; i++) {
    var _imageId = NieuwsService.nieuws[i].image;
    if (_imageId != "") {
        var uriString = "Web/Lists/getbytitle('Afbeeldingen%20voor%20nieuwsberichten')/Items(" + _imageId + ")/File";

        NieuwsService.createRequest(requestUrl, baseUrl, uriString).then(function (response) {
            var _parser = new DOMParser();
            var _xmlData = _parser.parseFromString(response.data, "text/xml");

            var _entry = _xmlData.getElementsByTagName("entry");

            var _imageUrl = "http://sharepoint" + _entry[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "ServerRelativeUrl")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            //Display
            $('#imageList').append("<li><a href='#'>" + _imageUrl + "</a></li>");
            NieuwsService.images.push(_imageUrl);
        })
    }
}

var _createRequest = function (requestUrl, baseUrl, uriString) {
    var promise = $http.get(requestUrl, {
        params: {
            "baseUrl": baseUrl,
            "uriString": uriString
        }
    })
    return promise;
}

NieuwsService.createRequest = _createRequest;
return NieuwsService;
```

So the question is, how do I get the responses in the order I make the calls?

Comment: This is because your $http calls are done asynchronously. They will return whenever their calls finish regardless of the order.

Comment: @RonnieTroj That's what I thought too, but I googled how to fix that and mostly what I found was that I must make a promise and return it so it will only go back to the for loop after it got the return of the `$http`. How do I make is synchronously? Because that was the only way I could find.

Comment: it is a bad practice, http as sync service can create unwelcome ui behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and array of promises, then use $q.all that will resolve when all the requests are done, and you will have the result of each one in the same position where you added the promise.

Answer (score 1):

$http is ASYNC by design, it means that each HTTP will go out in the same order but the response depends on many cases (network,dns, server response time  ext...)

you should design your code in a way that it will take that into consideration.

[You can use promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1):

As @RonnieTroj pointed out, the ajax calls are asynchronous and there is no defined order in that respect.

However, if you want to chain api calls such that you get responses in a specific order, then your only option is nesting calls in the following way:

```
call1.then(function(data1) { //first call
    call2.then(function(data2) {//second call after first call completes    
     //and so on
    }) 
})
```

However, the issue with this method is that it will take more time because you are essentially making the calls sequential in nature(one call executes, then another instead of parallel async calls.)

Comment: I think that's not the right solution, because I want it dynamically.

Comment: If you want responses in a specific order, this is the only way. If you want to wait for all calls to finish without any specific order then Leandro's answer works fine.

Comment: Is dynamic, you can add as many as you want and you will get them in order, but will resolve when all of them arrives, is the only way.

Comment: @TarunDugar So you're saying that if I use the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), it still won't work?

Comment: no, if by 'work' you mean getting responses in a particular order.